# I want to use a variable set in function in main program but errors in declaring variable

Tags: c++, function

I have declared and set a variable in a separate .cpp file but not the main file. I want the value given in the function to be used in the main program. I have included below the main file, function file and header file.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "create_character.h"

int main() {
  set_gender();
  set_age();
  std::cout << "Your character is a " << age << " year old "
  << gender << "." << std::endl;
}
```

character.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "create_character.h"

std::string set_gender()
{
  std::string gender;
  std::cout << "Would you like your character to be male or female? Type m for male or f for female.";
  std::cin >> gender;

  if (gender == "m")
  {
    gender = "male";
  }
  if (gender == "f")
  {
    gender = "female";
  }
}

int set_age() {
  int age;
  std::cout << "How old is your character?";
  std::cin >> age;
}
```

character.h:

```
#include <string>

std::string set_gender();
int set_age();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions are non-void functions, thus they have to return some value. You have a function `std::string set_gender()` in which you create a variable `gender`, you set this variable but never return it from the function. The same applies to your `int set_age()` function:

```
int set_age() {
  int age;
  std::cout << "How old is your character?";
  std::cin >> age;
  return age;
}

std::string set_gender()
{
  std::string gender;
  std::cout << "Would you like your character to be male or female? Type m for male or f for female.";
  std::cin >> gender;

  if (gender == "m")
  {
    gender = "male";
  }
  if (gender == "f")
  {
    gender = "female";
  }
  return gender;
}
```

Furthermore, when you call these functions, you have to assign their return values to a variable so you can use the returned values later:

```
int main() {
  const std::string gender = set_gender();
  const int age = set_age();
  std::cout << "Your character is a " << age << " year old "
  << gender << "." << std::endl;
}
```

Note, that when you declare a variable, you can only use the variable in the scope where this variable is declared. The scope is given by the `{}` brackets. So when you create a variable `age` in your `int set_age()` function, you can only use this variable in this `int set_age()` function, not outside the function. You can, however, copy the value somewhere else, to another variable - that's what `return age;` does. Then you can assign this returned value to a new variable in your `int main()` where you can use this variable in the scope of the `int main()` function.

Also, on a side note - you should use some include guards in your header file so that you'd ensure that the file would only be included once in the translation unit (cpp file). You can either use `#pragma once` statement at the beginning of the header file, or you can do it using preprocessor macros, which is more portable:

character.h:

```
#ifndef PATH_TO_CHARACTER_H_ // include guard
#define PATH_TO_CHARACTER_H_

#include <string>

std::string set_gender();
int set_age();

#endif // PATH_TO_CHARACTER_H_ // end of include guard
```